# How do I make an alias that shows only the date?

Tags: xubuntu, alias, date

Exactly as it says. What code should I use to make an alias to show me only the date, and not the time also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alias dateonly="date +%D"
```

check `man date` to see all the possible % formats, there's plenty of them :) for instanc,e change %D to %F for a different date format.

Comment: `%x` ("locale's date representation") is often a good choice

Comment: or even better, something that anybody understands `date --rfc-3339=date` totally unambiguous.